# Problem with MOSFET driver driving output

Tags: voltage, mosfet, current, resistors, mosfet-driver

I'm using this [MOSFET driver IC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20005677A.pdf).

Below is the schematic of the high side:

[image]

I followed figure 6-3 and 6-5 for the ICs schematics connections.

I have not populated the LED branches off of the gate outputs on all of the drivers (high side and low side).  One thing I noticed in capturing this data was that the Vboost signal starts where
it is supposed to be (~37V) but then drops down to near system voltage (~24V) and never recovers to what it should be after the first pulse.  This seems to me to be the root of this issue however I am not sure how to address it.  I would imagine that the voltage
at the Vboost pin should recover back up to the ~37V it was before the input pulses started.

These screenshots were taken with a 2.7nF boost capacitor.  I had tried the configuration previously mentioned with 10nF as the boost capacitor connected to Vdd.  The first few cycles were elevated but they decayed quickly to the system
voltage (i.e no boost).  So it looks like it helped a little with the boosting but ultimately decayed in the same way the 2.7nF boost capacitor did.

I have noticed that while this circuit runs in its current state, the high side MOSFET is getting warm quickly during operation, likely due to a weak turn on voltage not turning the MOSFET on all the way.

There is a drawing to show the voltage across the load.  I am currently using a 1.8 ohm resistor to simulate the load that will be present in the final application, a 24VDC brushless DC motor.  Since it is a 1.8 ohm resistor, the load current
was determined by dividing the voltage pulse amplitude by the resistance.  Since the signal is ~50% duty cycle the practical current would actually be half of that calculated result.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you've picked the wrong chip for the job. It won't work at 37 volts with bootstrapping and, you need bootstrapping to get what you want.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more clear on why it won't work @Andyaka

Comment: Do you understand what high-side bootstrapping of MOSFETs achieves?

Comment: Yes @Andyaka, this IC seems to have internal charge pump and provides the Vboost pin to add a bootstrap capacitor, right?

Comment: Yes but your circuit isn't using a bootstrap circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka, the boostrap capacitor makes sure that while switching an high-side load, the Vgs is always greater than the Vth of the MOSFET. And the MOSFET that I have used is https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFS7730-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563aad5921dc

Comment: But, the bootstrap circuit is not activated in your circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka, could you tell me how to activate it? Or please explain a bit more clearly because, I have done the circuit as per the datasheet recommendations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142752/discussion-between-newbie-and-andy-aka).

Comment: Look at the figures you mention 6.2 and 6.4 and 6.5. The bootstrapping is activated when the sense pins connect to the MOSFET source and the bootstrap capacitor also connects to the source. 24 volts as a supply is fine and ignore the 37 volt drivel I made earlier.

Comment: Looks like you can only run  pwm with a wide duty cycle range at around 5kHz - you’re at around 35kHz. Seems you need to be running 50% at that frequency. Also which mosfet are you using?  It seems this chip is made for a specific use case, so its operational constraints need to be adhered to. If you were hoping for a ‘normal’ boosted highside driver, then you’ve picked the wrong device methinks.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit is not working because the bootstrap subcircuit cannot do its job. A NMos is enabled once its Gate voltage is higher than its Source, and a boostrap is doing exactly that by building voltage atop the Source. Following your schematic the bootstrap capacitor is not connected correctly, being tied directly to +24V (and not the Source).

Since it seems you are not using a sense resistor and want to connect Sense to 24V, look at FIGURE 6-5 of the datasheet, with one side of the capacitor directly at Source :

[image: Correct connection of the bootstrap diode]

A side note of importance: Input a TTL pin and support max +15V, it is not clear whether you connected it directly to +24V.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But since my Voltage is 24V, I have connected the Vboost to Vdd as per figure 6-3? So, which figure should I follow?

Comment: Could you please clarify on what you meant regarding the TTL pin? I am not able to understand.

Comment: For the TTL Input, the datasheet specifies :
`TTL-Compatible Input with Internal Pull-Down Resistor` and
`Input Voltage, VIN ->  –0.5V to +15V`

Comment: Figure 6-3 shows a **preferred** configuration for supply voltages of 20V to 36V. So there's nothing wrong with tying the boost cap to the supply input.

Comment: @Newbie : Could you try connecting both Sense pins to the Source instead of 24V?
Mixing figures `6-3` and `6-5` and see if it works. I don't understand

Comment: And what is your mosfet? High switching frequency + high gate capacitance could be a culprit, the charge pump not being able to drive the gate.

Comment: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFS7730-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563aad5921dc - This is my MOSFET

Comment: Mosfet Gate capacitance looks to be nearly 10 times what the driver expects.

Comment: @Newbie A pretty big mosfet! Following Kartman comment, look at `FIGURE 3-5: Gate Turn-On Delay vs. Gate Capacitance`, you're nearly out of chart. No time to do it right now, but reading again the datasheet at the light of this information would give some clues on frequency/duty cycle. Maybe you could reconsider the driver, or the fet.

FYI, this driver `can turn on a 2000 pF MOSFET in approximately 550 ns` or `1500pf in 400ns` which is a lot lower than yours. Cross-multiplying, that's about 3.7us for yours, but you are probably past the capabilities of the driver (5.6mA sink/source).

Comment: @GCarles, Thank you for your response. Could you just include the values and info in your actual answer in simple terms for me to understand. Also, I lost when you said 3.7us? Could you please explain a bit more on that point?

Comment: @GCarles, could you explain on my above comment please?